# create eclipse groovy-java project with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, groovy

I have a Java-Groovy Eclipse project that I build with Maven. I have added the Maven Groovy plugin to the pom.xml such that I can build/test the Java and Groovy sources on the command-line using Maven.

I would like to have some way to automatically generate the Eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files from my pom.xml. If I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it seems to assume that it's a Java project, so there's no way to (for example) run the tests in `src/main/groovy` from within Eclipse.

I'm using the STS Eclipse distribution, which includes support for Groovy/Grails. All I'm missing is a way to automatically create the appropriate `.classpath` and `.project` files.

Thanks!

P.S. I know IntelliJ is better, but I don't have a license

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? To make your project work seamlessly within Eclipse or to find a way to generate .classpath and .project automatically from your maven file? For example, Eclipse + the Maven plugin + the Groovy plugin works very well together.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to have the project work seamlessly within Eclipse. Specifically, I would like to be able to compile all Java and Groovy and run all tests (whether written in Java or Groovy) from within the IDE. Ideally, I would like to be able to automatically generate the structure of this project directly from the pom.xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try the Groovy-Eclipse m2eclipse integration.  It is available here:

http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/

With this installed, your maven projects will be automatically configured as groovy-eclipse projects when you import them into your workspace.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work very well, is there an update site for full releases (as opposed to the snapshot update site)?

Comment: No, we haven't moved this to a production update site yet.  I don't expect that this functionality will change much over time.

Answer (score 8):

Here is configuration I found that works when Java calls Groovy code 
and when Groovy calls Java code fitting good within groovy eclipse IDE plugin (nature).

There is no need for additional source folders for groovy. It just works!

Using:

```
mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.groovy</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to create a Groovy project just by calling *mvn eclipse:eclipse* you have to configure your project. As follows a snippet how you configure your maven eclipse plugin so that your project becomes a Groovy project in Eclipse. That snippet must go into your projects *pom.xml* by the way.

```xml
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <additionalProjectnatures>
          <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</projectnature>
        </additionalProjectnatures>
        <sourceIncludes>
          <sourceIncludes>**/*.groovy</sourceIncludes>
        </sourceIncludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
```

When you now call *mvn eclipse:eclipse* maven creates the *.project* and *.classpath* files. *.project* contains the new project nature what makes it a Groovy project and *.classpath* contains the ***/*.groovy* what makes Eclipse treating any file that ends on *.groovy* as a source file.

Please see also http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/provide-project-natures-and-build-commands.html

Answer (score 1):

There is another best way to create maven groovy project. Please follow below steps:

- Navigate to https://start.spring.io/ from your browser.
- Select project as maven and language as groovy as shown below.
  [image: selection image]

- Select other options as per your build requirement like packaging, java version and project name.
- Now click on **Generate** radio button at the bottom and a maven groovy project will be downloaded.
- Open Eclipse and import the downloaded maven project and it's ready to use for your groovy scripting with maven integration.